# Microsoft Access ODBC Call to MySQL Failed with No Error Information

Tags: mysql, database, microsoft-access, sql, odbc

I'm trying to connect Access to a View Table in an MySQL Database that I have access permission to.

However, when I select the table to import, the following error message pops up:

[image: Error Message]

Which is great - it's always nice to get error feedback - but the error has no feedback information at all simply saying

> ODBC -- Call Failed
>
> [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.10-log] (#0)

Which is not useful.

I've double checked that I have permission to see the table (I got temporary edit permission, but that didn't help either), and I do - I can access it through other sources.

I've double checked that my ODBC connector is working correctly, and I've been able to use it to connect elsewhere (Excel).

I'm just looking for the ability to access the table and make Access queries. Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: Have you followed [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html)?

Comment: The issue is in step 5 of the documentation - The error shows up after I click 'OK' to import the data table and before I have to select an identifyer

Comment: Can it be a firewall problem?

Comment: Just disallowed it and re allowed it in my firewall, no change. It's not a firewall issue.

Comment: Did you try to disable the firewall totally?

Comment: @harrymc, I can't disable the firewall entirely, it's a work computer with the firewall administered by the employer. Besides, disabling a firewall entirely to connect to the database seems like a bad idea anyway...

Comment: I meant it as a test only.

Comment: @harrymc, you make a good point. I'll see if I can get them to disable it for a bit

Comment: @harrymc I managed to get it disabled for a bit and there was no change, same error